# Firebase auth persist in nodejs app? (get auth code from web app)

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, electron, jwt

Hey so I'm trying to persist login with my electron app. I use Firebase UI on the frontend in a nuxt app to log the user in. When I call HTTPS Callable functions, the authorization header is automatically send with the request.

I am trying to now make a flow like the following:

> 1. Click “Get auth token” which opens browser and passes in `client_id`
> 2. Browser gives an `auth code`
> 3. Copy `auth code` and paste into app
> 4. App verifies the user with token and pulls in details like uid, name etc
> 5. This token lives for a month before logging the user out

Is there a way I can mint a custom token that lives for 30 days with the firebase SDK somehow? As in I hit a custom end point in my web app which generates a long lasting token that I can paste into my app?

I am asking this because I am exploring the source code of the [wip menubar](https://github.com/marckohlbrugge/wip-menubar) and they use a similar strategy with the token auth.

I know I can update the current user using the following (from [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1874#issuecomment-637506043))

```js
const user = new firebase.User(userData, userData.stsTokenManager, userData)
firebase.auth().updateCurrentUser(user)
```

[image]

Comment: This is closest to what you're asking for, I think: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

Comment: I was thinking I could just pass the idToken from the client to the electron app and reauthenticate using `signInWithCustomToken(token)` from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth). Going to give it a go tomorrow and if not, will try your solution. Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen